# Post featured image column on admin post list page

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails

I have a client site which accepts images from users as posts. For moderation, we are opening each draft post which obviously takes a lot of time if  a hefty amount of images are moderated.

So, Is there a way to show featured images of the post on the admin post list page as a column?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what I'm using, cobbled together from snippets found online... It's uses a filter on `manage_posts_colummns` to re-jig the headers and an action on `manage_posts_custom_column` to add the row level data.

```
function custom_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns = array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'featured_image' => 'Image',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'comments' => '<span class="vers"><div title="Comments" class="comment-grey-bubble"></div></span>',
        'date' => 'Date'
     );
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_posts_columns' , 'custom_columns');

function custom_columns_data( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
    case 'featured_image':
        the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
        break;
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_columns_data', 10, 2 );
```

You can also use this on custom post types by filtering on `manage_CPTNAME_posts_columns`.

Answer (score 14):

Use this hook to add custom column to admin post/page list view.

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'add_img_column');
add_filter('manage_posts_custom_column', 'manage_img_column', 10, 2);

function add_img_column($columns) {
    $columns['img'] = 'Featured Image';
    return $columns;
}

function manage_img_column($column_name, $post_id) {
    if( $column_name == 'img' ) {
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');
    }
    return $column_name;
}
```

Put this code in your `functions.php`

Comment: nothing to display

Comment: Are you sure your post has featured image? Can you show me one screenshot? This code works fine for me.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/UM67XYl.jpg here it is

Comment: I asked you to show screenshot of featured image in single post. Where you have uploaded it. i.e http://mervin.info/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/screenshot-1-300x209.png

Comment: actually, there was plugin that was causing problems

Comment: I had to change to the second function to the following:
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');
return true;

Comment: Need to have the second function echo, not return, the image.

Comment: @busyjax can you please elaborate? What was the problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: Wanted to show a column of small image thumbnails which were featured images of posts, so without opening to edit the post, it was easy to just moderate post from the admin posts page.

Comment: This works perfect, better than the jnthnclrk answer that works too, but it removes the rest of the columns, this one keeps it. Cheers Mate...

Answer (score 6):

Based on @Mangesh Parte code, you can have featured image at first column, before title.

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'add_img_column');
add_filter('manage_posts_custom_column', 'manage_img_column', 10, 2);

function add_img_column($columns) {
  $columns = array_slice($columns, 0, 1, true) + array("img" => "Featured Image") + array_slice($columns, 1, count($columns) - 1, true);
  return $columns;
}

function manage_img_column($column_name, $post_id) {
 if( $column_name == 'img' ) {
  echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');
 }
 return $column_name;
}
```

Comment: Man thank you, this is a really good implementation.

Comment: Hy Otinane, is there any chance this only be apply to "Post Entries" and not to the rest of the custom posts type!

Answer (score 2):

This code shows how to add the featured image column to a 'books' custom post type (CPT). Replace in the first line word 'books' with the slug of your custom post type.

```
add_filter('manage_books_posts_columns', 'add_img_column');
add_filter('manage_posts_custom_column', 'manage_img_column', 10, 2);
function add_img_column($columns) {
    $columns = array_slice($columns, 0, 1, true) + array("img" => "Featured Image") + array_slice($columns, 1, count($columns) - 1, true);
    return $columns;
}

function manage_img_column($column_name, $post_id) {
    if( $column_name == 'img' ) {
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');
    }
    return $column_name;
}
```

You can find more information here
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column